# How should i handle calling modal widow from controller under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a modal window that will open under some conditions.
I did create a modal window that is opening on button click. What should i change?

My view:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popupModal">open</button>
    <div id="popupModal"
         class="modal hide fade"
         tabindex="-1"
         role="dialog"
         aria-labelledby="popupModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">


        ...some html
    </div>
</div>
```

my controller:

```
if (some conditions)
                    {
                        //here i want to open my modal window somehow
                    }
```

Comment: You're using bootstrap modals?

Comment: @mathiasfc, yes

Comment: I updated my answer with an example, any doubt ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check these conditions in the button [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event,

```
$(button).click(function(){
     if (some conditions)
     {
         $("#popupModal").modal("show");
         //$("#popupModal").show();
     }
});
```

I've created jsFiddle with an example for you: [JsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/1aeur58f/465/)

Comment: what should i do if those conditions are boolean methods  from controller, what access database?

Comment: @VolodymyrHnot I'm not the best person to respond to you, but how would I do this: you need to figure out a way to send the return of boolean methods to the javascript, or you can do these validations in the code behind and there call a script for show the bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 0):

From your controller Send your option in data array when you load your view.
for example, your code should be Something like this..

Controller:

```
$data = array();
if (some conditions)
{
    $data['option1'] = 'modal1';
}
else{
    $data['option2'] = 'modal2';
}
$this->load->view('your view file', $data);
```

View:

```
if($option1){
    // modal 1 html
}
else{
   // modal 2 html
}
```

Try this. i hope you get an idea.